# VBA Dictionary not behaving as expected

Tags: dictionary, ms-access, vba

Using a Dictionary in Access VBA, but retrieving values is prooving a problem. Can anybody tell me how to get around this, or what I am doing wrong?

So I am looping through a bit of code and set up a dictionary

```
           For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
                If Not dict.Exists(.Fields(i)) Then

                    If i = 0 Then
                        dictValue = "ID"
                    Else
                        dictValue = "F" & CStr(i)
                    End If

                    dict.Add .Fields(i), dictValue
                Else
                    'Duplicate column name error
                     Err.Raise 514
                 End If

            Next
```

The .Fields values from the dataset represent a single row of data extracted from a table and the dictionary sets up as expected.

Later accessing the dictionary to retrieve values is causing a problem:
serviceRequestId = dict("Service Request ID") is adding a new key to the dictionary as if the key does not exist, but it does, so I am getting a duplicate key added! This applies whichever key value I try to retrive from the dictionary. A brake point prior to the dereferencing shows that the correctly setup dictionary has not changed, and that the key added during the loop still indeed exists.

Any thoughts on this much appreciated!

Comment: Where is your dictionary declared? I'm presuming that above code is part of a function/sub, where else is it being called? can you also post the code as to how you are trying to retrieve the information from dictionary

Comment: Check if a Key Exists, then retrieve the item by this key: `If dict.Exists("Orange") Then ...`. Case sensitivity: `dict.CompareMode = BinaryCompare`.

Comment: probably a typo, but you are testing if one equals zero (`If 1 = 0 Then`) .

Comment: Yes the declaration is within the same function: It was late bount to start but switched while seeking answers 
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary 
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

Its not called outside of this function at the moment or between establishing the loop and the attempted retrieval. 

Its not a typo, both copied and paste from same string and double checked.

Comment: Sorry misread, yes typo on the condition, but not in the string used in the retrieval statement.

Comment: intersting quirk with dict.Exists . 
If dict.Exists("Service Request ID") Then serviceRequestID = dict("Service Request ID")  returns False, so of course the retrieve is not called, yet braking on the line after and dict.Item 21.Value = "Service Request ID"

Comment: Case sensitivity - has been set on BinaryMode, but tried both ways. 
dict("Service Request ID") : Empty
dict.Exists("Service Request ID") : True
dict.Item(21).Name = "F20" 
dict.Item(21).Value = "Service Request ID"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries can store any kind of object as a key or value

This line is storing the Field object itself as the key not it's value.

`If Not dict.Exists(.Fields(i)) Then`

In the diagram blow I stored the Field object in the dict and inspected it in the locals window.

[image]

### Here is what you actually want to do

```
    If Not dict.Exists(.Fields(i).Value) Then
        dict.Add .Fields(i).Value, dictValue
    Else
        'Duplicate column name error
        Err.Raise 514
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas Sorry didnt notice the answer - spot on!

Comment: I'm happy that I was able to help.  Happy Coding!

Comment: Great answer, but I'd like to point out you still have a typo in `If 1 = 0 Then`...

Comment: @VictorMoraes that was part of the OP's test.  But thanks I removed it because it wasn't relevant to the answer.